# ServiceStack - How does PUT work in RegisterService?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

so I had a look at [this RegisterService.cs on github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/b425168196d93784c3852480e74b316f920765a9/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs#L74). I notice when the endpoint is PUT, it gets redirected to POST method:

```
public object Put(Register request)
        {
            return Post(request);
        }
```

While in POST, there is this snippet:

```
var existingUser = userAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session, null);

            var registerNewUser = existingUser == null;
            var user = registerNewUser
                ? userAuthRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUserAuth, request.Password)
                : userAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(existingUser, newUserAuth, request.Password);
```

So if it is an existing user, the `RegisterService` would update instead of creating a new row. But when testing PUT in Postman, if the username and email haven't been changed, an error will show up:

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "ValidationException",
    "Message": "Validation failed: \r\n -- UserName already exists\r\n -- Email already exists",
    "StackTrace": "[Register: 5/09/2015 3:32:38 AM]:\n[REQUEST: {UserName:JIMMYNIKAIDO123,FirstName:JAY,LastName:NIKAIDO,DisplayName:JIMMYCHAN123,Email:JIMMYNIKAIDO123@OUTLOOK.COM,Password:JIMMY123,AutoLogin:True,Continue:YES}]\nServiceStack.FluentValidation.ValidationException: Validation failed: \r\n -- UserName already exists\r\n -- Email already exists\r\n   at ServiceStack.FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.ValidateAndThrow[T](IValidator`1 validator, T instance, String ruleSet)\r\n   at ServiceStack.FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.ValidateAndThrow[T](IValidator`1 validator, T instance, ApplyTo ruleSet)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.RegisterService`1.Post(Register request)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)",
    "Errors": [
      {
        "ErrorCode": "AlreadyExists",
        "FieldName": "UserName",
        "Message": "UserName already exists",
        "Meta": {
          "PropertyName": "User Name"
        }
      },
      {
        "ErrorCode": "AlreadyExists",
        "FieldName": "Email",
        "Message": "Email already exists",
        "Meta": {
          "PropertyName": "Email"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Do I change the username and email to get it updated? I don't think it is practical: what if I want the username and email to stay the same but just need to change a small field such as First Name? How to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

The Register Service will update the existing user based on the currently authenticated User (as referenced by the Users Session), i.e:

```
var session = this.GetSession();
var existingUser = userAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session, null);
```

The issue is that you're not sending an authenticated request so it doesn't recognize you as an existing user looking to update their information and instead thinks you're trying to register a new user, i.e:

```
var registerNewUser = existingUser == null;
var user = registerNewUser
    ? userAuthRepo.CreateUserAuth(newUserAuth, request.Password)
    : userAuthRepo.UpdateUserAuth(existingUser, newUserAuth, request.Password);
```

This is why you're getting a 'UserName already exists' error. You need to send an authenticated request to update your User info.